# How to use vm-translator module in Python?

Tags: python, nand2tetris

someone explain how to use this module to convert a VM file to asm file. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Command line -   `vm-translator fileName.vm`

Python code -

```
import os
os.system("vm-translator fileName.vm")
```

And maybe the next time read the documentation before asking a question.